# storing values in a string to be used in a Select Case statement

Tags: string, vb6

Say I have a string that looks like this...

```
Dim Value as String
Value = "373, 273"
```

My goal is to be able to use the VALUE string in a case statement...

So something along the lines of

```
Dim Number as integer
Number = 273

Select Case Number

Case Value
   Msgbox "Value is 273"

Case else
  'do nothing
End select
```

When I run this case statement - it does not read the VALUE (273) therefore it just goes to case else.

How can I use VALUE in my select case statement so that it recognizes the value of it???

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @ProGrammer updated

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here.. It seems like you're just trying to check if the `Value` contains `Number`, in which case you'd just use `Value.Contains(Number.ToString())`

Comment: @ProGrammer Its tagged VB6

Comment: @ProGrammer any idea how to do this in VB6?

Comment: Did it by accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
Dim Number as Integer = 273
Dim Value = "373, 273"

Dim numAsString = CStr(Number)
If InStr(1, Value, numAsString)
    MsgBox("Value is " & numAsString)
End If
```

Comment: I need this in a case statement :/ i dno how to go about that

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense in a `Select Case`

Comment: well it does in this case. I'm trying to move away from harcoding values (272, 373) and rather have it table driven (storing numbers in VALUES string). So previously it was Case 273, 373. Now i'm trying to have the select case statement read the VALUE string - this way if i need to add another number - i don't have to publish the code, can simply update the DB

Comment: That is an entirely separate concern. Instead of `Dim Value = "373, 273"` you'll be getting the values from a query but it will still run through the same code in the exact same fashion.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to simplify it instead of writing out a Query that grabs data from DB. I end up with VALUE (that consists of 27 numbers).

Comment: Case 273, 373 isn't equivalent to Case "273, 373". In the first you're saying the case handles integers 273 and 373. In the second you're saying the case handles the string literal "273, 373". The best solution really depends on what you need to do depending on which value is match. If if it's just any value then maybe store the valid values in a collection and check if the number you're comparing is in the collection. If you need to do something different for each value then it's more likely you need to hard code it.

Comment: I switched to If Statement and it does the job. Thanks. Only thing is it should be instr(1,Value,numasstring)